# Условия на тип возвращаемого значения метода при использовании await?

Tags: c#, async-await, tpl

Есть метод:

```
public async T Method()
{
   T result = await doSomeStuff();

   return result;
}
```

Какие условия должны быть выполнены для `T`, чтобы этот метод можно было вызвать:

```
public async void AnotherMethod()
{
    await Method();
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

По идее, `await` можно использовать для любого типа, в котором есть метод `GetAwaiter`, возвращающий реализацию интерфейса `INotifyCompletion`:

```
public AlexsAwaiter GetAwaiter()
{
    return new AlexsAwaiter();
}

class AlexsAwaiter : INotifyCompletion
{
 public bool IsCompleted
 {
   get
   {
     ...
   }
 }
 public void OnCompleted(Action continuation)
 {
   ...
 }
 public void GetResult()
 {
   ...
 }
}
```

Тип, возвращаемый `GetResult` и будет возвращаться из `await`.

Подробнее лучше почитать например в книге

> Дэвис Д. - Асинхронное программирование в C# 5.0 - 2013г.

[или тут](https://weblogs.asp.net/dixin/understanding-c-sharp-async-await-2-awaitable-awaiter-pattern)